# Ошибка при обращении к API Яндекс.Директ

Tags: java, веб-программирование, post, яндекс-директ

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая отправляет POST запрос на Яндекс.Директ. Использую их примеры https://tech.yandex.ru/direct/doc/start/index-docpage/
Но при отправке POST запроса выдаёт ошибку:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <213.180.204.225> != <soap-sandbox.direct.yandex.ru>
```

Помогите разобраться в чём проблема.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/campaigns");
        //Вместо ТОКЕН стоит мой OAuth токен
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ТОКЕН");
        String jsonPost =
                "{\"method\":\"get\"," +
                        "\"params\":{" +
                        "\"SelectionCriteria\":{}," +
                        "\"FieldNames\":[\"Id\",\"Name\"]}}";
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonPost);
        post.setEntity(input);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (respEntity != null) {
                String content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
                System.out.println(content);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```